# How intervals field in GranularitySpec impact data ingestion?

Tags: druid

What is the purpose of *intervals* field in *GranularitySpec* and importantly, how does it impact the data load or ingestion ?

For e.g. If I have data from `2014-01-01 to 2017-09-30` in a file and I specify intervals value as `"intervals" : ["2016-01-01/2017-12-31"]`. What would happen during data load in this scenario ?

Would really appreciate any help with this understanding. Thanks.

---

The [document](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/index.html) just says as below without much info on its impact:

**intervals:**  A list of intervals for the raw data being ingested.

Answer (score 1):

The intervals field acts like a filter. If you have your intervals in the granularitySpec set to 2016-01-01/2017-12-31, then any data outside of that range will not be loaded.

Comment: Your answer matches the [documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-ingestion-spec.html#define-granularities). However, when playing around with the `intervals` field in `quickstart/tutorial/updates-overwrite-index.json` and the corresponding input file, it seems the value gets ignored, and everything gets ingested, even values that lie outside of the defined intervals range. So why would this not work?